# Is there an in-game guide to find heart pieces?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In Twilight Princess there is a fortune teller that will give clues to help you find heart pieces. In Skyward Sword there is a fortune teller, but as far as I can tell he does not provide similar clues.

Is there a different in-game way to find clues to the location of heart pieces in Skyward Sword?

Comment: Not from what I can come up with. I haven't found or seen anything on google about it, nor have I found anything in-game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, There is no in-game guide. You got to go online or just explore and/or listen to hints from NPCs.